# unique pair of cells where order is not important

Tags: string, matlab, unique

I have a cell array of pairs of strings:

```
str={'A','BB','A','A'}
pairs=str(nchoosek(1:numel(str),2));

pairs =
6×2 cell array

{'A' }    {'BB'}
{'A' }    {'A' }
{'A' }    {'A' }
{'BB'}    {'A' }
{'BB'}    {'A' }
{'A' }    {'A' }
```

and I want to be able to have an index for the unique pairs regardless of order, in the sense that `A-BB` and `BB-A` are the same pair. the function `unique` only gives the unique labels A,BB.

when I try `unique(cell2mat(pairs),'rows')` I get an error because "Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent".

when I tried `table2cell(unique(cell2table(pairs)))` the order matters and I get

```
3×2 cell array
{'A' }    {'A' }
{'A' }    {'BB'}
{'BB'}    {'A' }
```

I would like to be able to `find` \ `ismember` such that  only

```
{'A' }    {'A' }
{'A' }    {'BB'}
```

are unique and that the index for the `A-BB` contains also the `BB-A` case.
help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sort(..., 2)` to sort within each row of `pairs` and then apply `unique(... 'rows')` with two outputs. However, that use of `sort` does not work for cell arrays of char vectors. The solution is to convert to a string array:

```
[result, index_unique, index_repeated] = unique(sort(string(pairs), 2), 'rows');
```

If you need the result as a cell array of char vectors you can convert back:

```
result = arrayfun(@char, result, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: thank you, this indeed generates the unique list, but not the indices of them in the entire list, just one index of where they appear.  The idea is to have an indices where the pair A-BB is at rows 1,4,5.

Comment: @yourds You want the third output of `unique`, that is, variable `index_repeated` (see edited code)

Comment: yes, that is indeed what I was missing. thanks you !